# import a submodule with its name from a module

Tags: python, python-import

I have a function called `prepared_db` in submodule `db.db_1`:

```
from spam import db

submodule_name = "db_1"
func_name = "prepare_db"
func = ...
```

how can I get the function by the submodule name and function name in the context above?

**UPDATE**:

To respond @histrio 's answer, I can verify his code works for `os` module. But it does not work in this case. To create the example:

```
$ mkdir -p spam/db
$ cat > spam/db/db_1.py
def prepare_db():
    print('prepare_db func')
$ touch spam/db/__init__.py
$ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:spam
```

now, you can do the import normally:

```
>>> from spam.db.db_1 import prepare_db
>>> prepare_db()
prepare_db func
```

but if you do this dynamically, I get this error:

```
>>> getattr(getattr(db, submodule_name), func_name)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1b6aa1216551> in <module>()
----> 1 getattr(getattr(db, submodule_name), func_name)

AttributeError: module 'spam.db.db_1' has no attribute 'prepared_db'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, you need to add the function to the `__all__` variable in the `__init__.py` file, so that would be something along the lines of:

```
from .db_1 import prepare_db

__all__ = ['prepare_db']
```

After that, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 6):

It's simple. You can consider module as object.

```
import os

submodule_name = "path"
func_name = "exists"

submodule = getattr(os, submodule_name)
function = getattr(submodule, func_name)
function('/home') # True
```

or [just for fun, don't do that]

```
fn = reduce(getattr, ('sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3', 'fn'), module)
```

**UPDATE**

```
import importlib
submodule = importlib.import_module('.'+submodule_name, module.__name__)
function = getattr(submodule, func_name)
```

Comment: I had tried your suggest before, but it hadn't really worked in the case. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Answer updated. Indeed your case little more complicated :)

Comment: do you have an explanation why it works in `os` module but not my case?